# Error while trying to get sample directx applications to work

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx

I am reading a book on directx 11 and I have undertaken advised steps in order to be able to run the sample applications. Despite all of these steps, I am left with the following error:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory@24 referenced in function "public: __thiscall Effect::Effect(struct ID3D11Device *,class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (??0Effect@@QAE@PAUID3D11Device@@ABV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)  BlendDemo   C:\Users\cmcl1\OneDrive\Documents\Chapter 9 Blending\BlendDemo\Effects.obj  1

What would the fix to this error be? Note, the steps I took can be found at the following link: https://www.d3dcoder.net/Data/Book4/d3d11Win10.htm

Comment: I believe the function `D3DX11CreateEffectFromMemory` requires that you link with `Effects11d.lib` (for debug versions) or `Effects11.lib` (for release builds). Are you doing this?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel is right. To run the samples in Luna's _Intro to 3D Game Programming with DirectX 11_, we had to build the included Effects framework project ourselves to create the **Effects11d.lib** static library. From memory we may also have needed to build the dynamic library **Effects11d.dll**. In any case the process was outlined in the book's introduction. Note the Effects framework was deprecated not long after its publication in 2012.

Comment: For problems of lnk2019,  please read the similar thread: [what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix). It is mostly caused by missing libraries.

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the latest version of the *Effects for Direct3D 11* library from [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/FX11). It's also available as a [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/fx11_desktop_2017/) package and a [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/tree/master/ports/effects11) port.

The Effects framework is considered legacy, and the support for building the `fx_*` profiles in the latest version of the `FXC` HLSL compiler will output a warning that it's deprecated. The key thing is that you won't find an equivalent "Effects framework" for DirectX 12. For more information see [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/effects-for-direct3d-11-update/).

> Frank Luna's book is excellent, but was published *just* before the DirectX SDK was deprecated along with D3DX9, D3DX10, and D3DX11. Instead of installing the legacy DirectX SDK itself (assuming you are using VS 2012 or later), you should use DirectXMath which is included in the Windows SDK per [this migration guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dxmath/pg-xnamath-migration), the *Effects* framework **fx11_desktop_2017** NuGet, and [**Microsoft.DXSDK.D3DX**](https://walbourn.github.io/legacy-d3dx-on-nuget/) NuGet package. See [this blog post](https://walbourn.github.io/book-recommendations/).